# ACF block gutenberg aligncenter don't work

Tags: php, custom-field, css, block-editor, buttons

I'm starting with creating Gutenberg blocks with ACF.
I would like to create a simple button, so far so good.
My problem comes from the center alignment. When I align my element to the left and right it works, but centering it no longer works.

How could I go about resolving this?
In your opinion, is it appropriate to change the initial css of the positions with something more personalized? If for example I want to replace float:right with `display:flex, justify-content: center`?

**HTML / PHP**

```
$className = 'myclass';
if( !empty( $block['align'])){
    $className .= ' align' . $block['align'];
}

<div class="<?php echo esc_attr($className);?>">
  <a href="#" role="button" tableindex="0" class="mybutton">My button</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mybutton{
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}
``
```